# list indices must be integers, not str. BATTLESHIP

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, integer, indices

The following Python Code:

```
def CheckIfSunk(Board):
  Row, Column = GetRowColumn()

  if Board[Row][Column] == "A":
    Ships = "Aircraft Carrier"
  elif Board[Row][Column] == "B":
    Ships = "Battleship"
  elif Board[Row][Column] == "S":
    Ships = "Submarine" 
  elif Board[Row][Column] == "D":
    Ships = "Destroyer"
  elif Board[Row][Column] == "P": 
    Ships = "Patrol Boat"
  elif Board[Row][Column] == "P": 
    Ships = "Patrol Boat"
  elif Board[Row][Column] == "N": 
    Ships = "NEW"


  Board[-1][Ships] -= 1
  if Board[-1][Ships] == 0:
    print Ships + " Sunk"
```

I receive this error:

> Board[-1][Ships] -= 1 
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

How can i fix this, any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`Ships` is a string.
Your `Board` contains strings, so you are trying to get element of string by `str` not by `index`.

Interpreter said exactly the same:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, im not the best at python so im still a bit confused

Comment: Board at position -1 is a string, not a dict. So you can't access the string with another string. You should have something like Board[-1] = {'Battleship': 10, ...}. Instead you have something like Board[-1] = 'oh my'

Answer (score 0):

In the last third line of your code

**Board[-1][Ships] -= 1**

> To refer the elements in 2-dimensional array i.e in PYTHON a list containing 2 lists we use **integer** values as index.

The variable **Ships** is a **String** *or* **None** if any of the above conditions are not fulfilled, so either way **Ships** is not integer.

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

So, you need to access the list(*arrays*) using **integers**